# Can't import my module with Python.NET from the same directory as the project

Tags: python, .net, module, python.net

I'm working on a .NET project and encountered this issue when i decided to try embedding some Python code a different person wrote. I couldn't import his module with `Py.Import` and got `Python.Runtime.PythonException: No module named 'mypythonscript'`
The module is in the same directory as the code. I even checked the working directory with `os.getcwd()` to make sure I didn't mess up with directories. I ended up creating a seperate project to experiment and couldn't import the module in it too.
Here's the code of the test project

```
using Python.Runtime;


Runtime.PythonDLL = @"*my python311.dll path*";
PythonEngine.Initialize();
using (Py.GIL())
{
    var recognizerModule = Py.Import("mypythonscript");

}
```

mypythonscript.py is in the project directory and looks like this (although I don't think it matters what's inside it)

```
def say_hello():
    return "Hello!"
```

I've read the documentation, some stack overflow threads and watched a couple of videos. Everyone seems to do exactly what I did and everything works for them.
Someone please help me I'm losing my mind.

p.s. Importing a built-in module like `os` works fine